# Commit a docker container but doesn't have any changes I made

Tags: docker

I pulled mysql from docker hub and am able to run this container. After create some databases and tables, I want to commit this container to a new image in order to persistent my changes. By doing this, I hope the new image can be shipped to other members which will include all the data. I use below command:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
3aca4ff8790d        mysql                                        "/entrypoint.sh mysql"   6 months ago        Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   lonely_liskov

$docker commit 3aca4ff8790d cooltoo/cooltoo_db:LATEST
```

When I run this new image, all my changes and settings are not there. How can I persistent my container into a new image with all my changes and settings?

Comment: The image probably has the data directory defined as a volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Henry was right; the MySQL container Dockerfile has /var/lib/mysql configured as a volume.

Your best bet (and the industry best practice) would be to put your changes in a Dockerfile (beginning with "FROM mysql").  Quoting the [docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/):

> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical order.

So if you take your data/schema/whatever and mysqldump it and put in an

`ADD foo.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/foo.sql`

...in there, you should be golden.

Comment: I didn't specify any volume when I launch mysql docker. Where can I find all the data storage? I have checked that my host doesn't have /var/lib/mysql directory.

Comment: As soon as a path is declared as a volume, changes to it are not retained. From the docs (http://lp7h.qr.ai): "If any build steps change the data within the volume after it has been declared, those changes will be discarded."